# Django - manage.py collectstatic saving to the wrong folder

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-settings, django-static

**Update:** looks like this is being cause by the django-heroku package and specifically the inherited whitenoise package, which in docs says your supposed to put

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

at the end of settings file, which I never did but it still enforces root being 'staticfiles' folder instead of assets folder

**Original Post:**

When I run python manage.py collectstatic it saves to a folder called staticfiles

I must have done something to make this happen, but I've searched for staticfiles and found no reference to it except 'django.contrib.staticfiles'.

Here is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    #some apps
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
#some more apps

    'tz_detect',
]

# some more code

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'media_root')
```

Expected outcome was for when python manage.py collectstatic is run, that an assets folder would be created, but this never happens.

The staticfiles folder in addition to files from static folder also contains a tz_detect folder (from static assets from 3rd party package), an admin folder, and a staticfiles.json

middleware section of settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    # some more middleware
    'tz_detect.middleware.TimezoneMiddleware',  
]
```

Comment: Can you provide a link to the `tz_detect` package?

Comment: Sure, but I think whitenoise package is the issue http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html . Here is tz_detect package https://github.com/adamcharnock/django-tz-detect

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking into this right now.  Can you add an update showing your `MIDDLEWARE`?

Comment: update question showing middleware change

Comment: I ran `grep -nr 'staticfiles' path/to/tz-detect` and a few other combinations, and found nothing, so `tz-detect` is unrelated to the issue.  That being said, I think `whitenoise` might be causing the issue, but I can't seem to recreate your problem, so I think there is something important that isn't included in your question.  Are *all* 3rd party apps/middleware included in `INSTALLED_APPS` and `MIDDLEWARE` (not including default packages)?

Comment: I include all third party packages in my comment. Except for I added import django_heroku at top of my settings.py file. And django_heroku.settings(locals()) at bottom of settings.py https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration

Comment: whitenoise is a dependency of django_heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that it isn't possible to change the name of your `STATIC_ROOT` using `django_heroku`, without *monkey patching* the package.

The line `django_heroku.settings(locals())` takes all the local variables (ie `STATIC_ROOT`) and passes them into the `settings` function found at `django_heroku/core.py`.

If you take a look at line 89:

```
config['STATIC_ROOT'] = os.path.join(config['BASE_DIR'], 'staticfiles')
```

You will see that whatever value you set for `STATIC_ROOT`, the package will override it with `staticfiles`.

> **Note** that the following may have unintended consequences, and you shouldn't do them.

Here are 2 *monkey patch* solutions:

- change the value of `STATIC_ROOT` after you call `django_heroku.settings(locals())`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
```

- modify `django_heroku/core.py line 89:` to the following:

```
if 'STATIC_ROOT' not in config:
    config['STATIC_ROOT'] = os.path.join(config['BASE_DIR'], 'staticfiles')
```

this will prevent `djano_heroku` from overriding the `STATIC_ROOT` if you have already defined it.

Again, I don't recommend doing this because there *might* a good reason that Heroku forces you to use the name `staticfiles`, and this might cause your server to break, or worse, parts of your server might silently fail (which means debugging will be a nightmare).